# C# double precision problem

Tags: c#, double, precision

Imagine that **a - b < c** (a, b, c are C# doubles). Is it guaranteed that **a < b + c**?

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Let's say that the arithmetical overflow doesn't occur unlike the following example:

```
double a = 1L << 53;
double b = 1;
double c = a;

Console.WriteLine(a - b < c); // Prints True
Console.WriteLine(a < b + c); // Prints False
```

Imagine that **Math.Abs(a) < 1.0  &&  Math.Abs(b) < 1.0  &&  Math.Abs(c) < 1.0**

Comment: How is this related to C# or any specific data type (or even programming)? Looks like pure math to me.

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: No, it's all about precision.

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: Because it has to do with the languages level of precision on non-integer arithmetic

Comment: @jgauffin and @BeRecursive: of course! :)

Comment: Actually the math is quite trivial and it has something to do with the datatype. Imagine things like 3.0 * (1.0/3.0) == 1.0 etc. Mathematically correct, in C# might not hold exactly depending on the datatype.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No. Suppose a = c, a very large number, and b is a very small number. It's possible that `a - b` has a representation less than `a`, but `a + b` is so close to `a` (and bigger) that it still ends up being most precisely representable as `a`.

Here's an example:

```
double a = 1L << 53;
double b = 1;
double c = a;

Console.WriteLine(a - b < c); // Prints True
Console.WriteLine(a < b + c); // Prints False
```

EDIT:

Here's another example, which matches your edited question:

```
double a = 1.0;
double b = 1.0 / (1L << 53);
double c = a;

Console.WriteLine(a - b < c); // Prints True
Console.WriteLine(a < b + c); // Prints False
```

In other words, when we subtract a very small number from 1, we get a result less than 1. When we add the same number to 1, we just get 1 back due to the limitations of double precision.

Comment: or the other way around, I also have the feeling it's like that.

Comment: It gets even weirder when `a=c=double.MaxValue`. Then both are false.

Comment: Great example, sure. But actually we deal with micro-numbers, not with values around double.MaxValue. Please read EDIT for more information.

Comment: @levanovd: `1 << 53` is *way* smaller than double.MaxValue. There's no overflow going on here.

Comment: @levanovd: I've provided another example which fits into your limits.

Answer (score 6):

no not always:

```
        double a = double.MaxValue;
        double b = double.MaxValue;
        double c = 0.1;
        Console.WriteLine(a - b < c); // True
        Console.WriteLine(a < b + c); // False
```

Answer (score 2):

This link speaks about floating-point arithmetic properties, and could be very interesting:

[**FLOATING-POINT FALLACIES**](http://zuras.net/FPFallacies.html)

In particular, search for ***Properties of Relations***